# Why does Stack Exchange prevent the author of an accepted answer from deleting her own answer?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes the author of an answer realizes it's wrong, but doesn't know the right answer or can't fix it immediately.

Other times a question is edited so it no longer matches the accepted answer.

Why does Stack Exchange prevent the author from deleting her own answer in these instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It's been that way since the beginning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14932/allow-author-of-accepted-answer-to-delete-it-in-certain-circumstances). As far as I can tell it's... because Jeff Atwood wanted to *encourage* you to edit the answer instead of deleting it.

> I believe editing the accepted answer (that you own, and thus can edit by definition) to point to the answer you believe to be more correct is sufficient in this case.
>
> If you feel very strongly you could strikeout  your entire post, or elide it completely leaving just a link to the better answer.

--[Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/60107/131112)

Comment: and he got a net 18 downvotes for proclaiming that, wow

Comment: Another comment suggests flagging for a mod to delete it, which makes we wonder if deleting and undeleting the same answer would remove the acceptance tag.

Comment: @Oddthinking - you got me curious enough to ask. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288179/does-deleting-and-undeleting-the-accepted-answer-remove-the-acceptance-tag

Comment: Yes doesn't work, I actually checked the code to see if I could work around it before answering...